# TeamCity - 10.0.5 no compatible build agents

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, build-agent

I'm wondering if someone could help me out with this issue please.

First up the background, we've been using TeamCity for database deployments for a while. Today we upgraded to 10.0.5. All fine.

The issue we have is with SQL 2016 database projects. I'm trying to get the database project to build in TeamCity. The build 'Visual Studio' setting in the build was set to 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2015' this causes issues as it cant build it. So I changed it to be 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2017' and I installed 'Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017' on the TeamCity box.

Now when I click the run button I get a message back saying
"Warning no enabled compatible build agents......".

Its almost as if the build agent is allowed to use the VS2015 MSBuild but not the 2017 one and I'm not sure how to authorise it to be able to.

I've attached some screenshots of the screens as well.

Thanks,

Nic[image: BuildConfig]
[image: Agent]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to resolve this simply be restarting the server.

Thanks,

Nic